# Dynamic programming to find minimum number of coins

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand part of a question I have as my HW but it really looks like Chinese...

Let's say we have coins `x_1, x_2, x_3, ... x_n`.  `x_1 = 1` always.
We want to give a certain amount of money in a minimum number of coins.
Then we use dynamic programming.

And now I don't understand this  -  `c(i,j) = min { c(i-1,j), 1+c(i,j-x_i) }`
where `c(i,j)` is the minimal amount of coins to return amount `j`.

Comment: What don't you understand? `c(i,j)` is the recursive formula, you do an exhaustive search - for each coin you check what is better - to take it, or not to take it

Comment: @amit why it is the minimal between those 2??

Comment: Because you are looking for the minimal number of coins, by checking all possible solutions, you get the minimal overall.

Comment: @amit this is not what I mean...
why possible solution is 1+c(i,j-x_i)?? where does it come from?

Comment: `c(i,j-x_i)` is the minimal number of coins to get the value `j-x_i` using only coins `i,i+1,...,n` (This is the induction hypothesis, that's what the recursive formula ensures us). Thus, `1+c(i,j-x_i)` is the minimal way to get `j-x_i` with the given set of coins + an extra coin valued `x_i`, which we decided to use.

Comment: I wrapped this discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c(i,j-x_i)` is the minimal number of coins to get the value `j-x_i` using only coins `i,i+1,...,n` (This is the induction hypothesis, that's what the recursive formula ensures us). 

Thus, `1+c(i,j-x_i)` is the minimal way to get `j-x_i` with the given set of coins + an extra coin valued `x_i`, which we decided to use.

From this, `c(i,j) = min { c(i-1,j), 1+c(i,j-x_i) }` is actually choosing "what is best" exhaustively:

1. Taking the current coin, and checking recursively the rest of the smaller problem
2. Deciding not to take it - and again, checking the smaller problem recursively.

Taking the minimal of those ensures us (because it is done exhaustively - over all possibilities) that `c(i,j)` is minimal.